# Swift - array of tuples or struct of arrays for classification?

Tags: swift, time-complexity

I'm implementing a search algorithm, and I want to show the results from most relevant to least relevant. I have an array of profiles from which I want to get an `OrderedSet` of the profiles' IDs, in order of relevance. My classifications, from most relevant to least relevant, are:

- `completeMatch`
- `firstWordMatch`
- `notFirstWordMatch`
- `firstWordContains`
- `notFirstWordContains`
- `socialContains`

I can call `profiles.reduce(into: // Intermediate model) { ... }` on the profiles to do this. However, I'm wondering what my intermediate model, which I would then convert into the `OrderedSet` of profile IDs, should be:

- An array of tuples composed of the profile ID and the classification as an enum:

```swift
enum SearchResult: Int {
    case completeMatch = 0
    case firstWordMatch = 1
    case notFirstWordMatch = 2
    case firstWordContains = 3
    case notFirstWordContains = 4
    case socialContains = 5
}

let results: [(Profile.ID, SearchResult)] = profiles
                .reduce(into: [(SentProfile.ID, SearchResult)]()) { /* ... */ }

searchResults: OrderedSet<Profile.ID> = .init(
    results
        .sorted { lhs, rhs in
            let (_, lhsClassification) = lhs
            let (_, rhsClassification) = rhs
            return lhsClassification.rawValue < rhsClassification.rawValue
        }
        .map { profileID, _ in profileID }
)
```

- Or a struct of each classification as independent ordered sets:

```swift
struct SearchResult {
    var completeMatch: OrderedSet<SentProfile.ID> = []
    var firstWordMatch: OrderedSet<SentProfile.ID> = []
    var notFirstWordMatch: OrderedSet<SentProfile.ID> = []
    var firstWordContains: OrderedSet<SentProfile.ID> = []
    var notFirstWordContains: OrderedSet<SentProfile.ID> = []
    var socialContains: OrderedSet<SentProfile.ID> = []
    
    func joined() -> OrderedSet<SentProfile.ID> {
        return completeMatch
            .union(completeMatch)
            .union(firstWordMatch)
            .union(notFirstWordMatch)
            .union(firstWordContains)
            .union(notFirstWordContains)
            .union(socialContains)
    }
}

let results: SearchResult = profiles
                .reduce(into: SearchResult()) { /* ... */ }

searchResults = searchResults.joined()
```

My main concern is time complexity, and I can't quite seem to decide which is better between the two.

Comment: in recent SDKs enums auto-synthesise `Comparable`, so you can just compare them directly without having to access their raw value (and as they start from 0 by default  you don't even need to specify their raw value, or even make them conform to Int)

Answer (score 0):

Creating, populating and then merging the multiple sets within the struct feels far heavier weight than sorting tuples.  You can also simplify the work involved by reducing the work in creating the intermediate data structures:

```
enum SearchResult: Comparable {
   case completeMatch
   case firstWordMatch
   case notFirstWordMatch
   case firstWordContains
   case notFirstWordContains
   case socialContains
}

// as before, just naming the tuple's elements for clarity in the example
let results: (id: Profile.ID, match: Searchresult) = ... 


let ordered: NSOrderedSet = .init(
   array: results.sorted(by: {$0.match < $1.match})
      .map{$0.id}
)
```

This intuitiviely feels less time complex as the number of operations is reduced to a simple sort (which the compiler will optimise) and then a map.  It is certainly far easier to read and maintain.